while setting up firebase with flutter app for authentaction
Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.22631.3593]
(c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

E:\flutter self practice\filesharewithfirebase>flutterfire configure --project=filesharewithfirebaase
i Found 11 Firebase projects. Selecting project filesharewithfirebaase.
✔ Which platforms should your configuration support (use arrow keys & space to select)? · android, ios, macos, web, windows
✔ Which Android application id (or package name) do you want to use for this configuration, e.g. 'com.example.app'? ·
i Firebase android app  is not registered on Firebase project filesharewithfirebaase.
⠇ Registering new Firebase android app on Firebase project filesharewithfirebaase.
FirebaseCommandException: An error occured on the Firebase CLI when attempting to run a command.
COMMAND: firebase apps:create android filesharewithfirebase (android) --package-name= --json --project=filesharewithfirebaase        
ERROR: Package name for Android app cannot be empty

E:\flutter self practice\filesharewithfirebase>






i Firebase android app  is not registered on Firebase project filesharewithfirebaase.
i Firebase android app  is not registered on Firebase project filesharewithfirebaase.
i Firebase android app  is not registered on Firebase project filesharewithfirebaase.
⠇ Registering new Firebase android app on Firebase project filesharewithfirebaase.
FirebaseCommandException: An error occured on the Firebase CLI when attempting to run a command.
COMMAND: firebase apps:create android filesharewithfirebase (android) --package-name= --json --project=filesharewithfirebaase        
ERROR: Package name for Android app cannot be empty
✔ Which Android application id (or package name) do you want to use for this configuration, e.g. 'com.example.app'? · com.example.filesharewithfirebasecom.example.filesharewithfirebase erfire configure
i Firebase android app com.example.filesharewithfirebasecom.example.filesharewithfirebase is not registered on Firebase project college-c0823.a Firebase project to configure your Flutter application with · college-c0823 (college)
i Registered a new Firebase android app on Firebase project college-c0823.
i Firebase ios app com.example.filesharewithfirebase is not registered on Firebase project college-c0823.
i Registered a new Firebase ios app on Firebase project college-c0823.
i Firebase macos app com.example.filesharewithfirebase registered.
Failed to parse JSON response from Firebase CLI. JSON response: {
  "status": "success",
  "result": {
    "fileName": "GoogleService-Info.plist",
    "fileContents": "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>\n<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC \"-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN\" \"http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd\">\n<plist version=\"1.0\">\n<dict>\n\t<key>API_KEY</key>\n\t<string>AIzaSyA1pfZ5mtQXxChISwdgVJjUJZ-2Jsy0vHk</string>\n\t<key>GCM_SENDER_ID</key>\n\t<string>287444333228</string>\n\t<key>PLIST_VERSION</key>\n\t<string>1</string>\n\t<key>BUNDLE_ID</key>\n\t<string>com.example.filesharewithfirebase</string>\n\t<key>PROJECT_ID</key>\n\t<string>college-c0823</string>\n\t<key>STORAGE_BUCKET</key>\n\t<string>college-c0823.appspot.com</string>\n\t<key>IS_ADS_ENABLED</key>\n\t<false></false>\n\t<key>IS_ANALYTICS_ENABLED</key>\n\t<false></false>\n\t<key>IS_APPINVITE_ENABLED</key>\n\t<true></true>\n\t<key>IS_GCM_ENABLED</key>\n\t<true></true>\n\t<key>IS_SIGNIN_ENABLED</key>\n\t<true></true>\n\t<key>GOOGLE_APP_ID</key>\n\t<string>1:287444333228:ios:97573a0ab69af270b9a509</string>\n</dict>\n</plist>"
  }
}{
  "status": "error",
  "error": "Timed out."
}
FormatException: Unexpected character (at line 7, character 2)
}{
 ^


E:\flutter self practice\filesharewithfirebase>

error while connecting in app

You forgot to ask your question.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

did you find the fix? I'm facing the same issue

Your Android app is not registered on the firebase.
first of all go to firebase and then open the project which you created and after that you will see this 
on the add app go and add the android for your project

enter image description here
I error i got But i try  it will solve
when ask this ✔ Which Android application id (or package name) do you want to use for this configuration, e.g. 'com.example.app'? ·
you should provide you app package name
✔ Which Android application id (or package name) do you want to use for this configuration, e.g. 'com.example.app'? · com.example.flutterdatatest

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
